# why am I getting java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libc++_shared.so" not found in my Android project?

Tags: android, android-studio, cmake, android-ndk

Hello I got this Android app project and in this part of the code:

```
        init {
        try {
            System.loadLibrary("c++_shared")
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Could not load library due to: ${Log.getStackTraceString(e)}")
            //throw e
        }
    }
```

I get:

```
    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libc++_shared.so" not found
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1077)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:998)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1661)
    at com.assembleinc.kidstunes.media.MediaPlaybackService.<clinit>(MediaPlaybackService.kt:237)
    at com.assembleinc.kidstunes.media.MediaBrowserController.onStart(MediaBrowserController.kt:56)
    at com.assembleinc.kidstunes.ui.main.MainActivity.onStart(MainActivity.kt:72)
```

I got CMake version 3.18.1-g262b901
And in my gradle I got:

```
    compileSdkVersion 33
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.test.music"
    minSdkVersion 23
    targetSdkVersion 33
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 'androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'

    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            cppFlags ""
            arguments "-DANDROID_STL=c++_shared"
        }
    }
}
externalNativeBuild {
    cmake {
        path "CMakeLists.txt"
    }
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
ndkVersion '21.3.6528147'
```

No matter how many times I click in Android Studio:

1. Refreshed C++ linked projects
2. Clean
3. Build
   Everything seems fine but when running I get the previous mentioned error.

Does anyone have idea, why is this happening?

Thanks in advance for everyones help.

Comment: Why are you trying to load libc++_shared.so? If your own native library has a dependency to it, then it ought to get loaded automatically when you load your own library.

Comment: Were you able to fix this problem? I am having the same issue, but as in your case I am not trying to load any shared library explicitly. I switched from NDK 21.3.6528147 to NDK 26.1.10909125 and it builds fine but at the time it loads to the devices it crashes with the same error as yours.

Comment: Seems like I may have to switch back to NDK 21.3.6528147, it is possible that 26b is not supported for app development as yet.

Answer (score 0):

Comment by @Michael just underneath the original question answers the asked question, but I just wanted to make sure that those who stumble on this issue can easily find the answer.

```
externalNativeBuild {
    cmake {
        cppFlags ""
        arguments "-DANDROID_STL=c++_shared"
    }
}
```

Problem is the following line of code in the build.gradle file

**arguments "-DANDROID_STL=c++_shared"**

This is not required as any library needed by the native code will be included in the shared lib built by the native toolchain regardless.

Another problem you may encounter is that of other libraries required for your native code and the recommended NDK builds for building them. For example, in my case, tensorflow team recommends NDK 21b and if you face the same problem, you might be able to solve the problem by degrading to earlier version of the NDK. I faced this problem due to mismatch in NDK builds (earlier I was trying with NDK 26b) for some of the libraries and got the error the OP asked, the error disappeared when I went back to NDK 21b.